# Reading pdf content with itextsharp and C#

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I'm looking for a way to select text n characters on either side of a keyword search using itextsharp (v5.5.8).  I've gotten to the point where I can use the SimpleTextExtractionStrategy() and return a list of pages where the searched text is found (supposedly).  When I do a manual search using PDF Viewer Search, sometimes it's there and sometimes it can't find it on the page itextsharp says it's on.  Sometimes, not at all.

The idea is to be able to return 40 characters on either side of the found keyword to allow the user to be able to find the reference easier when they look at the actual document.  In another question, I saw a reference to additional text retrieval functions (LocationTextExtractionStrategy,  PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(myReader, pageNum) in combination with some Contains(word)).

Where can I find examples of how to use these functions?  And how to create a better strategy?

My current code:

```
public  List<int> ReadPdfFile(string fileName, String searthText)
{
    string rootPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~");
    string dirPath = rootPath + @"content\publications\";

    List<int> pages = new List<int>();

    string fullFile = dirPath + fileName;
    if (File.Exists(fullFile))
    {
        PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(fullFile);
        for (int page = 1; page <= pdfReader.NumberOfPages; page++)
        {
            ITextExtractionStrategy strategy = new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy();

            string currentPageText = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdfReader, page, strategy);
            if (currentPageText.Contains(searthText))
            {
                pages.Add(page);
            }
        }
        pdfReader.Close();
    }
    return pages;
}
```

And an example of the output using a simple response.write command...

Document 1.pdf 1 3 
Document 2.pdf 1 2 3 4

The numbers after the file name are page numbers where the searched for keyword is found.  However, in Document 1, the keyword is also found on the very top of page 4 in the "References" section that began on page 3.  It should be found twice in the References.

Thanks,
Bob

P.S.  apparently 5.5.8 doesn't have the iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.TextExtractionStrategy method...

Comment: *apparently 5.5.8 doesn't have the iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.TextExtractionStrategy method...* - that's not a method but an interface and in iTextSharp it's [ITextExtractionStrategy](https://github.com/itext/itextsharp/blob/master/src/core/iTextSharp/text/pdf/parser/ITextExtractionStrategy.cs).